# GPT PMBR size mismatch after dd clone

Tags: hard-drive, gpt, dd, migration

I am migrating my Ubuntu EFI boot system to a larger hdd. I used the command

```
dd if=/dev/sdb of=/dev/sda
```

I did not dismount the input file before copying and the output file was fresh unpartitioned space. I have successfully booted from the new larger hdd.

- `fdisk -l` reports:

  > GPT PMBR size mismatch
- `gdisk` reports the old drive size (200GB) and
- PMBR is reporting the new hard drive size (2TB).

The error states `gdisk w` (write) command will work, however gdisk help recommends command `xe` (relocate backup to end of disk).

My goal is to remove the old drive and use the new drive as a primary boot disk with my old grub install intact.

Shall I just go ahead an expand the partitions or should I use one of these commands?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Do as the `gdisk` prompt suggests: Use the `e` option on the experts' (`x`) menu to relocate the data structures to the end of the disk. You can accomplish the same thing in `parted` or GParted if you prefer. IIRC, they do it semi-automatically, although they ask for confirmation.

Once you've moved the GPT backup data structures, you can resize your partition(s) using GParted.

Comment: You should believe this guy - [he wrote `gdisk`](http://www.rodsbooks.com/gdisk/).

Comment: I wound up using gparted from a live usb. I removed the partitions and rewrote the partition table on the new drive. From there, I wrote robot steps: gparted copied the partition structure of the old disk, and meanwhile also resized the partitions and copied data for the new disk. It did everything while I slept.

Comment: @ZakriKneebone: As I don't see the "why your should do this" explained here: because the GPT gets stored on the first *and* last sector of the disk just in case the one on the first sector fails, it still has a back-up... (and an upvote!)

Comment: @RodSmith An alternative **non interactive** solution would be welcome too. After cloning using `dd` to a larger drive this issue always comes back. Handy if the clone script can fix the incorrect "backup GPT". I can't find a relocate option in GPT fdisk (sgdisk) version 1.0.3. Never mind https://superuser.com/questions/905756/bash-scripting-parted-for-gpt#answer-906139 tells that `-e|--move-second-header` is the sgdisk option.

Answer (score 2):

Just another datum, I ran into this today resizing an EBS volume on my EC2 instance.  I solved it by running `growpart /dev/nvme0n1 1`, which resized my partition correctly.

Answer (score 1):

I want to post an expanded explanation of my trials and error for those trying the same since documentation is rather fragmented and points to several different techniques.
I wound up using gparted from a live usb. I removed the partitions and rewrote the partition table on the new drive. Gparted has a step sequencer: it copied the partition structure of the old disk, and meanwhile also resized the partitions and copied data for the new disk. It did everything while I slept.
Using dd also required a manual update of fstab file which I skipped. I then tried ddrescue (from the Universe package via Synaptic, not Software Center) from live usb which reported it did not work with gpt. It referred me to gparted.

Comment: Good one too!  Lots of people will be learning from this Q&A...